# SSL validation failed for sagemaker endpoint when an image is passed for inference

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I trained a custom yolov5 model and deployed it to a sagemaker endpoint bby  referring this blog : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/scale-yolov5-inference-with-amazon-sagemaker-endpoints-and-aws-lambda/

Model Deployment :

```
model = TensorFlowModel(model_data=model_data,
                        framework_version='2.8', role=role)

predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                            instance_type=INSTANCE_TYPE,
                            endpoint_name=ENDPOINT_NAME)
```

Here's how I am trying to pass the image for inference to the sagemaker endpoint :

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
image_data = response['Body'].read()

# Resize the image to 640x640 using Pillow
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_data))
image = image.resize((640, 640))

# Convert the resized image to a NumPy array
image_array = np.array(image)

# 
image_data = np.array(image_array.astype(np.float32)/255.)
image_payload = json.dumps([image_data.tolist()])
```

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

ENDPOINT_NAME = 'yolov5-inference-test-new'

client = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2')

response = client.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
ContentType='application/json',
Body=image_payload)
```

But it throws a SSL validation failed error. I checked my region and the region of my notebook, boto3 client and sagemaker endpoint are all the same.

Interestingly, when I tried to pass a blank image to the endpoint ,it worked fine without any errors.

```
blank_image = np.zeros((modelHeight,modelWidth,3), np.uint8)

blank_data = np.array(blank_image.astype(np.float32)/255.)
blank_payload = json.dumps([blank_data.tolist()])
```

Please help me fix this.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVagr.png)

After referring some fixes , I checked my region and the region of my notebook, boto3 client and sagemaker endpoint are all the same, still the error persists.

Comment: Where are you trying to make the invoke_endpoint call from? Have you tried a different laptop/notebook instance/networking set up?

Comment: I am trying to call the endpoint from the same notebook I used to deploy the endpoint.

Comment: I suggest confirming if you can invoke the endpoint from a different notebook (different network config) or from your local laptop using the SDK or boto3

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking using other ContentType like `application/x-npy`, most likely the error caused by too big of payload as reference of S3 SDK. https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/discussions/7735